# Conda enviroment keep using python 2.7 instead of python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I created conda ennviroment with python 3.6, but unfortunately this env uses python 2.7 . Why? How can i fix it?

I think i could have some alias for python 2.7, but where should i try to find it and how should i change this?

```
$ conda create --name nn2019 python=3.6 numpy=1.13.3 scipy=1.1.0 
matplotlib tqdm scikit-learn=0.20.0 jupyter notebook

# ...

(base) jan@MacBook-Pro-Jan-2 ~
$ conda activate nn2019
(nn2019) jan@MacBook-Pro-Jan-2 ~
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.
(nn2019) jan@MacBook-Pro-Jan-2 ~
$ conda deactivate
```

As you can see there is still python 2.7 instead of python 3.6, what should i do?

Comment: Did you try using python version 3.7? In some packages 3.6 is not included anymore. Further you can install the packages later from within conda.

Comment: What's the output of `which python`

Comment: To add to the sanity checks `conda create --name nn2019 python=3.6 numpy=1.13.3 scipy=1.1.0 
matplotlib tqdm scikit-learn=0.20.0 jupyter notebook`  the output of this contained python 3.6 right? If yes, it must be a pathing issues and use list the output of `which python` as stated by @lincr

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH` before and after activation?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux OS then you have to export the path of the conda environment then you will be able to use python3.x. Use

```
export PATH="/Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

before running python command. Also you can include this path to *.bashrc* file for permanently active this conda environment.

Comment: This is contrary to recommended practice since Conda v4.4 (see [Release Notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)).